# ¿Como imprimir múltiplos de un numero pero no de otro?

Tags: java, bucle-for

Sigo aprendiendo bucles, como puedo lograr que mi programa imprima los múltiplos de 2 pero no los de 5? al poner la condición if(num==i%2 && num== i%5) me muestra evidentemente solo los de 5, trate de restar eso pero no lo conseguí o no encuentro manera de estructurarlo.

```
/*Objetivo: imprimir enteros que sean múltiplos de 2 pero no múltiplo de 5
mayor que 100 y menor que 1000
*/
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Problema3
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int num=0;
      for(int i=100;i<=1000;i++)
      {
         if(num==i%2) //multiplos de 2
         {
            System.out.println(i);
         }
      }
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer lo que deseas necesitas colocar el operador logico (y) && en java y decir que no es divisible entre 5 (que no es multiplo)

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      for(int i=100;i<=1000;i++)
      {
         if(i%2 == 0 && i%5!=0) //multiplos de 2
         {
            System.out.println(i);
         }
      }
  }
}
```